# MockRestServiceServer returns 404 status instead of mocking external service response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm writing an outbound `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` based service activator which sends a `POST` request to the 3rd party REST API and gets a JSON in response. The 3rd party REST API accepts JSON object as payload. The relevant test methods are as follows:

```
  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    server = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplateBuilder.additionalMessageConverters(
                httpMessageConverter).build());
    messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate();
    defaultDestination = new QueueChannel(1);
  }
```

and

```
  @Test
  void testOutboutSMSRequestHanlder() throws Exception {

    SMSTaskRequest request = new SMSTaskRequest("1", 
                               Arrays.asList(new SMSTask(1, "123456", "Test Message")));

    SMSTaskResponse response = new SMSTaskResponse("200", "OK", "task-status", 
                                 Arrays.asList(new SMSTaskStatus("1", "0 OK")));

    server.expect(requestTo("http://localhost/foo/bar"))
       .andRespond(withSuccess(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response), APPLICATION_JSON));

    messagingTemplate.send(outboundSMSRequestChannel, 
         MessageBuilder.withPayload(request)
        .setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).setReplyChannel(defaultDestination).build());

    SMSTaskResponse smsTaskResponse = messagingTemplate
        .receiveAndConvert(defaultDestination, SMSTaskResponse.class);

    assertThat(smsTaskResponse).isEqualTo(response);
  }
```

I get a 404 error for the external service request even after configuring my gateway as follows

```
@Component
public class OutboundSMSHandlerGateway {

  @Autowired
  private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter;

  @Bean
  public PublishSubscribeChannel outboundSMSRequestChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
  }

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundSMSRequestChannel")
  @Bean
  public HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handleGatewaySMSRequest() {
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("http://localhost/foo/bar");
    handler.setHttpMethod(POST);
    handler.setExpectReply(true);
    handler.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(httpMessageConverter));
    handler.setExpectedResponseType(SMSTaskResponse.class);
    return handler;
  }
}
```

The error stack trace is as follows

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://localhost/foo/bar] in the [bean 'handleGatewaySMSRequest'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/thoughtscape/sms/OutboundSMSHandlerGateway.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@19f9d595']; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: [<html>
    <head>
        <title>Valet - Not Found</title>

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: monospace;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        404 - Not Found
    </body>
</html>
]
, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=SMSTaskRequest(type=send-sms, taskNum=1, smsTasks=[SMSTask(taskID=1, recipient=123456, messageContent=Test Message, flashSms=null, characterCodingSet=null, smsCodec=null, successReport=null, failureReport=null, enableSmsReport=null)]), headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@38f502fc, id=43ed8efa-7aea-34bd-6884-1938ed65e9d3, Content-Type=application/json, timestamp=1602675489316}]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.exchange(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:210)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:320)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at com.thoughtscape.sms.SmsServiceApplicationTests.testOutboutSMSRequestHanlder(SmsServiceApplicationTests.java:87)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: [<html>
    <head>
        <title>Valet - Not Found</title>

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: monospace;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        404 - Not Found
    </body>
</html>
]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:593)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.exchange(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:196)
    ... 76 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MockRestServiceServer returns 404 status instead of mocking external service response

Don't confuse yourself: there is full no interaction with your mock server at all. You just perform a real HTTP call.

Let's analyze your code!

```
server = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplateBuilder.additionalMessageConverters(
            httpMessageConverter).build());
```

So, you try to mock some result of `restTemplateBuilder` and you are done here: no any reference to the server neither to the `RestTemplate`!

> I get a 404 error for the external service request even after configuring my gateway as follows

```
HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("http://localhost/foo/bar");
handler.setHttpMethod(POST);
handler.setExpectReply(true);
handler.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(httpMessageConverter));
handler.setExpectedResponseType(SMSTaskResponse.class);
return handler;
```

And what? Where is an interaction with the mock server?
See docs on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-client

The very important phrase:

> // Test code that uses the above RestTemplate ...

So, what you need to make it working properly is a `RestTemplate` bean injected into that `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`. And the same `RestTemplate` instance must be used from that `MockRestServiceServer.createServer()`. Only this way your HTTP outbound gateway is going to interact with the mocked `RestTemplate` which is going to pull answers from the mentioned mock server.

Otherwise the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` creates its own internal `RestTemplate` which knows nothing about mocking and is going to perform real request to the mentioned URL.

Comment: configured a `RestTemplate` bean and then it works injecting the same instance to the handler and mock server.